# Limiting the size of TEXT in MySQL for speed

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with a field that needs to store 512 characters. My question is this: can you limit the length of a TEXT field (VARCHAR stops at 255 - I can't use it) to 512 characters? If I do that, will MySQL run through the table quicker due to the fixed data length, or does it act a bit like VARCHAR in that the length can vary?

I don't have a table (at all) yet, but I'm very conscious about speed and size for the future. I found this article: [link text](http://www.linuxformat.com/wiki/index.php/PHP_-_Optimising_MySQL_queries) incredibly useful - maybe you will to!

Thanks a lot,

James

Comment: You won't get any speed improvements from that silly approach. Nobody runs through the table these days. Index does have exact position already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your mysql server. Since 5.0.3 you can store up to [65535 bytes in VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).

Comment: Strange. I checked my MySQL version and it's 5.1.49. Am I just doing something wrong? :P Thanks for your help nonetheless :)

Comment: CHAR is still have 255 limit. What engine and sql-mode do you use? I'm not sure about MyISAM, but it works just fine for me with InnoDB

Comment: I'm using the default: MyISAM and latin1_swedish_ci collation. If you could briefly summarise, what (apart from the CHAR thing) is better about InnoDB? Thanks.

Comment: Edit to post above: No need to explain - I've read around and found a few things. I will stick with MyISAM for now and just put up with the CHAR limit - thanks all the same though :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't really say how you are using the table, so I'll just throw this in. One option is to separate out the text field into another table and just have a reference to it in your original table.